# Customize Python Slicing, please advise

Tags: python, list, slice

I have a class that subclasses the list object.  Now I need to handle slicing.  From everything I read on the intertubes this has to be done using the `__getitem__` method.  At least in Python 2.7+ which is what I'm using.  I have done this (see below), but the `__getitem__` method isn't called when I pass in a slice.  Instead, a slice is done and a list is returned.  I would like a new instance of myList returned.

Please help me discover what is wrong.

Thanks!

```
class myList(list):

    def __init__(self, items):

        super(myList, self).__init__(items)
        self.name = 'myList'


    def __getitem__(self, index):

        print("__getitem__")
        if isinstance(index, slice):
            print("slice")
            return self.__class__(
                self[x] for x in range(*index.indices(len(self)))
                )
        else: return super(myList, self).__getitem__(index)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("\nI'm tesing out custom slicing.\n")

    N = 10
    L = myList(range(N))

    L3 = L[3]
    L02 = L[:2]
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

See [this note](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#additional-methods-for-emulation-of-sequence-types):

> `object.__getslice__(self, i, j)`
>
> Deprecated since version 2.0: Support
>   slice objects as parameters to the
>   `__getitem__()` method. (However, built-in types in CPython currently
>   still implement `__getslice__()`.
>   **Therefore, you have to override it in
>   derived classes when implementing
>   slicing.**

So, because you subclass `list` you have to overwrite `__getslice__`, even though it's deprecated.

I think you should generally avoid subclassing builtins, there are too many weird details. If you just want a class that behaves like a list, there is a [ABC](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections-abstract-base-classes) to help with that:

```
from collections import Sequence

class MyList(Sequence):
    def __init__(self, *items):
        self.data = list(items)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)

    def __getitem__(self, slice):
        return self.data[slice]

s = MyList(1,2,3)
# lots of free methods
print s[1:2], len(s), bool(s), s.count(3), s.index(2), iter(s)
```